# when I write python commands in cmd it always just says "python'

Tags: python, windows, installation, cmd

For example if i write `python -m pip install whatever` it just says "Python" and nothing happens. Any other command starting with `python` does that. `python3` causes the same issue. `py -m`, on the other hand, works.

I have windows 11, and I installed python 3.10 by downloading it from the python website.

The reason I asked this question is because many internet sources use `python`, and I had suspicions that my installation was broken because a particular package didn't work. However the package turned out to just be broken for different reasons. Since then I have resolved the issue by reinstalling windows.

Comment: We need more information about what you're using to answer this question.

Comment: @BlueRobin anything, any terminal would do that. However I have long resolved this issue by reinstalling windows

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. The reason that you are being downvoted however is because it doesn't make any sense. It would be helpful to have screenshots as well.

Comment: @BlueRobin I write anything starting with "python" into command line, for example "python -m pip install numpy", and every time it just writes me "Python" and nothing else happens

Comment: Including screenshots for this question would be very helpful

Comment: @BlueRobin I don't know what kind of screenshot you want, it is literally what I described and nothing more. Well I am already banned anyway due to this question

Comment: Good luck. I had the same problem in the past. I would recommend going to meta StackOverflow if you believe your question shouldn't receive as many downvotes as it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because you have not added the path to your python.exe file to PATH environment variable.
I have the same situation - see the first command on the [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqYHX.png), result - just
`python`. There are two ways to handle it:

1. Add the path to your python.exe file to PATH environment variable - it is simple to find in google search how to do it
2. Every time when you want execute some command in cmd just write not `python`, but the path to your python.exe file - in my case `D:\Miniconda\python.exe` (see the second command on the screen). If you use Anaconda/Miniconda, the path is Anaconda/Miniconda directory.